# wifiManager doesn't update unless I check WiFi List manually from settings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-wifi, wifimanager

I use `wifiManager` in Kotlin to get wifi network list with

`wifiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager`

`wifiManager!!.scanResults`

But the list doesn't get updated when I invoke `wifiManager!!.scanResults`(I call it every second).

For example let's say I create a new network called *net1* but It doesn't see *net1* directly

It updates only when I visit WiFi Settings manually *net1* shows up there at the settings, and the list updates. Finally wifiManager starts to see *net1*

How can I invoke what the phone does when I visit WiFi Settings/solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently android throttles scanning WiFi for foreground apps.

You can scan only 4 times in 2 minutes, and because I scan every second it just updates for 4 seconds every 2 minutes.

But if I visit WiFi settings device manually scans and the last scan results are displayed in `wifiManager!!.scanResults` if scan is failed/not completed.

I solved this disabling *Developer options -> Networking -> Wi-Fi scan throttling*